# How to enable tab and its content on click of a text in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I am working on a [website](https://jsfiddle.net/moshiuramit/02znsurj/embedded/result) on which I want enable button on click of a text in Javascript/Jquery.

The JQuery code which I have used in order to scroll down towards the bottom on clicking `view options` text are:

```
$(".view_profile_options a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sectionTop = $('.tab-contents').offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: sectionTop },
        'slow');
 });
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the JQuery code above so that on clicking `view options` text in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/moshiuramit/02znsurj/embedded/result), the hover for `tokyo` and its `content` gets enabled automatically.

Comment: What is 'tokyo'?

Comment: @RoughChop Check the fiddle at the bottom. There is a `tokyo` tab. I want that to get enable automatically (`with hover and content getting visible`) on click of a `view options` text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works like a charm:

```js
$(".view_profile_options a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sectionTop = $('.tab-contents').offset().top;
    
    var event = $.Event('click');
    event.currentTarget = $('.tab .tablinks')[2];
    
    $('.tab .tablinks:nth-child(3)').trigger(event);

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: sectionTop },
        'slow');
 });
```

Comment: Raguzzini Can you update it in the fiddle? In that way, it can be more easy for me to visualize.

Comment: In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02znsurj/50/embedded/result), I have integrated some grid classes from bootstrap because in my actual code base I have that. On adding that, it doesn't seems to work. Can you have a look ?

Comment: Raguzzini Sorry, I didn't add bootstrap grid classes initially.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. I have one last question. I have added a lot of lines beneath the tokyo `tab` and its `content` now. Now when I click on `view options`, I can only see the `content (not the tab)`. Is there any way we can see both `tab` and `content` ?

Comment: Out for dinner :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate clicking on the button. In your case as you have no button ID, I use selector by containing the desired text.

I have also removed your complex JavaScript Codes and wrote a simple Jquery instead to hide and show tabs and buttons:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".view_profile_options a").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var sectionTop = $('.tab-contents').offset().top;
      $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: sectionTop },
          'slow');
          $('button:contains("Tokyo")').trigger("click");
   });

 
   $("button").click(function(){
        //Display tab
        var city=$(this).text();
        $(".tabcontent").hide();
        $("#"+city).show();

        // Change class of button
        $("button").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
   })
 })
```

```css
.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tab-contents>.active
{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p  class="ml-2 mb-2 d-flex  view_profile_options"><a href=""> view options</a> <i class="ml-2 fas fa-2x fa-angle-right"></i></p>

<p>Click on the buttons inside the tabbed menu:</p>

<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>


<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>



<p>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks"">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-contents">
<div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>

</script>
```

Comment: I am wondering if you can make changes in the fiddle. In that way, it will be more easy for me to visualize.

Comment: I have updated the answer by adding new descriptions and code snippet @flash

Comment: Checking. Stay tuned.

Comment: Its looking good. Thanks for the help.  So on clicking `view options` text, it goes all the way towards the bottom. I am wondering what changes I need to do in the code snippet so that on clicking view options text, it goes only till `Tokyo` tab.

Comment: If you don't want to animate the scroll, just remove the jquery `animate`  and trigger `scrollTo` instead @flash

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that, using:

- A new attribute to target the button element,
- Then, use `.prop("disabled", false)` on that button.

Working snippet:

```js
$(".view_profile_options a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = "#" + $(this).attr("target");
    $(id).prop("disabled", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view_profile_options" >
  <a target="button1">Click me!</a>
</div>

<button id="button1" disabled>My button</button>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am wondering if you can make changes in the fiddle. In that way, it would be easy for me to visualize.

Comment: @flash Well, I don't really get how you want your fiddle modified. I don't see any disabled "button" in it.

Comment: Right, there is no button. I am calling `view options` as a text. On click of it, the hover section of `tokyo tab` and its `content` should get enabled automatically.

Comment: Can you check my problem statement ? Maybe it answers your question.